# Loop through JSON and display items with specific names

Tags: javascript, html, json, loops

I have the following JSON:

```
{ "Food" : [ { "Meat" : "beef lamb turkey",
              "Vegetables" : "broccoli potatoes carrots",
              "Fruit" : "apples bananas strawberries",
              "Sugar" : "candy softdrinks",
              "Dairy" : "milk cheese yoghurt",
              "Grains" : "wheat barley rice",
              "Fat" : "fries KFC",
            },
]
```

I am trying to loop through this, and display only the "Sugar" and "Fat" items.

I have this:

```
<script type="text/html" id="badFoods">
    <div>
        <% _.each(container.Food, function(food, i) {%>
            display the name here i.e Sugar and Fat
        </div>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
</script>
```

When I run this, I want it to display the following:

Sugar : candy softdrinks
Fat : fries KFC

Apologies, this might be a bit vague, just looking for a push in the right direction so I can get my head around this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#1
<% _.each(container.Food, function(food, key) {%>
  Sugar: <%= food.Sugar %> Fat: <%= food.Fat %>
<% }); %>

#2
<% _.each(container.Food, function(food, key) { %>
  <% _.each(food, function(value, key) { %>
    <% if (key === 'Sugar' || key === 'Fat') { %> 
      <%= key %>: <%= value %> 
    <% } %>          
  <% }); %>
<% }); %>
```